# Query Error on db connection

Tags: php, mysql

Looking on my error log I get the following error a lot:

```
[01-Mar-2011 04:31:27] exception 'Exception' with message 'Query failed' in /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/model.php:89
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php(275): Model::execSQl2('update articles...')
#1 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php(111): Article->save()
#2 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/pages/frontpage.php(21): Article->calculateRanking()
#3 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/pages/frontpage.php(27): FrontPage->updateRanking()
#4 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/index.php(15): FrontPage->showTopArticles('')
#5 {main}
```

If I go to the model.php file I see this:

```
static function execSQl2($query)
    {
    /*
            Execute a SQL query on the database
            passing the tablename and the sql query.
            Returns the LAST_INSERT_ID
    */


        $db = null;
        $lastid = null;
        //echo "query is $query";

        try
        {
            $db = Model::getConnection();
            $results = $db->query($query);
            if(!$results) {
                throw new Exception('Query failed', EX_QUERY_FAILED );
            }
            $lastid = $db->insert_id;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            /*  errors are handled higher in the
                    object hierarchy
            */

            throw $e;
        }
```

Does Anybody see an error, or i should look somewhere else?

Thank you and Regards,
Carlos

Edit:

This is the query: $lastid = parent::execSql2($query);

And this is the context:

```
function save() {

    /*
            Here we do either a create or
            update operation depending
            on the value of the id field.
            Zero means create, non-zero
            update
    */

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $this->title = addslashes($this->title);
            $this->description = addslashes($this->description);
        }

        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            if($this->id == 0 )
            {
                $query = 'insert into articles (modified, username, url, title, description, points )';
                $query .= " values ('$this->getModified()', '$this->username', '$this->url', '$this->title', '$this->description', $this->points)";

            }
            else if($this->id != 0)
            {
                $query = "update articles set modified = NOW()".", username = '$this->username', url = '$this->url', title = '".$this->title."', description = '".$this->description."', points = $this->points, ranking = $this->ranking where id = $this->id";
            }

            $lastid = parent::execSql2($query);

            if($this->id == 0 )
                $this->id = $lastid;

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            error_log($e);
        }
    }
```

Regards,
Carlos

Comment: Which query is getting failed? What is the query? post the query too

Comment: Throw the exception message with mysql error message. Do not change it to your custom message otherwise it will be very difficult to identify issue for you

Comment: How can I find our the query with the error? That is what I am trying to find.  So to fix the custom message should I just delete 'Query failed' on: throw new Exception('Query failed', EX_QUERY_FAILED ) ?  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As heximal said, it's probably an error in your SQL query. Copy and paste the full SQL being queried into PhpMyAdmin or a similar tool and see what errors (if any) come up. Often, the problem is simply a mistyped table or a missing value.
Of course you can also post the query here if you want SO help with it! :D

Comment: Thank you, How can I find: the full SQL being queried ? Should I start in the files on the error message? article.php , frontpage.php , index.php ? Regards,Carlos

Comment: Check `/home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php` line 275. The query should begin with 'update articles'. Paste this query on SO so we can check it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is propably in sql-query. Append to log query text and analyze it.